# Is there away to Find the angle in 360ْ dgree?

Tags: c#

I want to find an angle, similar to the one in the image. I have the point of the beginning of the line. I'm trying to find the angle form this formula:
`angle=Atan|(m2-m1)/(1+m1*m2)|`, but I'm getting the wrong result

Here's my code:

```
float slope1 = (259 - 177) / (518 - 482);
float slope2 = (700 - 259) / (1244 - 518);

double abs = Math.Abs((slope2 - slope1) / (1 + slope2 * slope1));
double Thita = Math.Atan(abs);
```

---

[image]

Comment: What is the expected value and what is the actual value you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you use double instead of float. Like this,

```
double slope1 = (259 - 177) / (double)(518 - 482);
double slope2 = (700 - 259) / (double)(1244 - 518);

double abs = Math.Abs((slope2 - slope1) / (1 + slope2 * slope1));
double Thita = Math.Atan(abs);
```

Comment: the proplem is in the answer it's 35 but that's wrong

Answer (score 0):

add (float) at divisor, you're doing int div truncation. print slope1, slope2 to debug.

`float slope1 = (259 - 177) / (float)(518-482);
float slope2 = (700 - 259) / (float)(1244 - 518);`

Comment: Even better, use `double` everywhere since the followings lines uses some `double`.